# Could Data have taken out Admiral Quinn?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In "Conspiracy," an enhanced Admiral Quinn mops the floor with both Riker and Worf, and chucks Geordi *through* the quarters' automatic doors. Could Data have incapacitated Quinn as easily as Worf taking out Picard, or would the altered admiral have some sort of a chance?

Comment: I've edited this to remove the "do you think" which made it read as though you were looking for opinions, and which are off-topic for this site.  If this changes the meaning of your question please feel free to revert.

Comment: When I read the question title I thought of Admiral Elli Quinn from Lois Bujold's Miles Vorkosigan series.

Comment: This is the 24th century.  Data can date whomever he wants.  However, it is considered inappropriate to fraternize with direct superiors, but since Adm Quinn doesn't appear to be in Data's direct chain of command, it's probably okay.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Data is extremely strong, consider this exchange from his trial in the episode ["The Measure of a Man"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)):

> RIKER: Your Honour, I offer in evidence prosecution's exhibit A, a rod
>   of par-steel. Tensile strength, forty kilobars. Commander, would you
>   bend that?
>
> PICARD: Objection. There are many life forms possessed of mega
>   strength. These issues are not relevant to this hearing.
>
> PHILLIPA: I'm afraid I can't agree, Captain. Proceed with you
>   demonstration, Commander.
>
> (Data bends the heavy rod neatly into a U shape)

[Tensile strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) is measured in force per unit area, usually in terms of megapascals; this page mentions that 1 bar = 0.1 megapascals, so 40 kilobars = 40000 bars = 4000 megapascals, significantly stronger than any type of steel listed in the table in the tensile strength article (edit: Dan Neely points out there is one I missed with a strength over 5000 megapascals), and about as strong as Kevlar which is used in bulletproof vests. Assuming Quinn's strength was just due to things like adrenaline rather than the parasites radically reengineering his whole body including the composition of bones and muscles (and there was no suggestion of such a thing in the episode), there's no way he could have been nearly that strong. And Data is also able to move much faster than a human, as shown in the episode ["The Naked Now"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now_(episode)) when he had to replace the isolinear chips in engineering in order to allow the ship to escape an exploding star. So yes, I think Data could have easily defeated him in physical combat.

Comment: Also, Data is impervious to the amount of physical trauma Quinn could have delivered. It showed that he is bullit proof in First Contact. Quinn could beat on Data on day and it would have no effect.

Comment: If you sort the table by tensile strength, you'll find there is one steel alloy listed that is substantially stronger at > 5000MP: "Steel, Micro-Melt 10 Tough Treated Tool (AISI A11)".  It's probably not the only alloy in that general range either; tool steels need to be much stronger than the materials they work to have reasonable lifetimes before being worn out.

Comment: I definitely agree that Data is super-strong. Though Quinn told Worf that he could kill him with one hit, or break his neck with one hit (I don't recall his exact words). That's some strength. Also, Quinn's strength must have been increased (and not just his adrenaline level), or else he wouldn't have easily brushed off Riker's hits, and barely been affected by Worf's. Quinn's speed didn't seem greatly increased, though, and he still had bones and flesh, so I can definitely see Data breaking him down easily. Also, Worf caused the admiral to yell in anguish, so he wasn't totally immune to pain.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, Data would mop the floor with an adrenalin/endorphin enhanced Quinn. The adrenalin/endorphin enhanced Quinn can manhandle a normal human or Klingon, but Data is orders of magnitude stronger that either race. He possesses mega-strength and has a very durable structure, Whereas Quinn is only a man and fragile by comparison.

The only thing that would make it even close is Data's programming to do the least amount of harm as possible. If Data went full out and got medieval on him it would be over in a second or two, with Data the victor.

Comment: I love the mixed metaphor of an *android* getting *medieval* on someone...

Comment: I should add that Quinn is also getting on in years. Even with the adrenal enhancement, he still is going to be less than he would have been had he been younger.