# How strong is Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In "Time's Arrow," Data carries an anvil with one hand quite leisurely; he lifts a larger anvil in "Thine Own Self." In addition, he lifts a large metal beam in "Hero Worship" and is considerably stronger than both Borgs and Klingons.

Has Data's physical strength ever been quantified, in the same way, for example, that his processing speed has? Is there any way to deduce his strength based on canon showings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could Data have taken out Admiral Quinn?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63645/could-data-have-taken-out-admiral-quinn)

Comment: Ah, but is he stronger than an elephant?

Comment: The Admiral Quinn question (and answers) doesn't mention a possible maximum physical strength for Data, right?

Comment: No, my answer there just referenced the fact that he could bend a bar with a tensile strength of 4000 megapascals (and since that's force per unit area, I suppose we could multiply by the area of his hand to estimate the force he was applying), but there was no indication that this was an upper limit.

Comment: I think the Admiral Quinn one should be closed as a duplicate of this one, once it has a good/accurate answer...  This one is wider, _and_ is something that more people are likely to wonder about.

Comment: Interesting video. I wonder if Tuvok or 7 of 9 could carry the anvil with one hand. I don't think that Tuvok could. Probably could carry it with two hands, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picard (in TNG : [The Offspring](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/164.txt)) offers his own assessment of Lal's physical strength. Since she was based on Data's own physiology, it's likely her strength is similar to his.

Obviously he's using hyperbole but there's no reason to assume his assessment is wildly inaccurate:

> **PICARD :** (frowns)
>   *If he must, fine. But I don't understand how he can call a five foot android, with heuristic learning systems and **the strength of a ten men**
>   a "child".*

We see him carrying a 2-300 pound anvil with one hand in "TNG: [Times Arrow](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/226.txt)". Someone with the strength of 10 men could easily accomplish this feat.

> Data casually reaches down with one hand -- AND PICKS UP THE ANVIL as
>   though it weighed an ounce. He starts toward the center of the room --
>   there's a noise of astonishment from the Bellboy.

and of course the most obvious feat of "meta-human" (mega) strength from TNG : [Measure of a Man](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/135.txt)

> **Riker :** *Your honor, I offer into evidence
>               prosecution's exhibit A. A bar
>               of plasteel with a tensile
>               strength of forty kilo-bars.*
>
> Data easily bends the bar.

Comment: "Strength of ten men" is a common cliched phrase that just means "really strong"--see http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheStrengthOfTenMen for example--so it's doubtful that Picard was giving a literal quantification of her strength.

Comment: I see you've edited, but I disagree with your claim that "there's no reason to assume his assessment is wildly inaccurate"--there's very good reason to think it's quite possible it could be wildly inaccurate, namely that it's a cliched phrase that is commonly uttered by people who have no idea what the actual numerical value of the strength is. If Picard said she was "strong as an ox", or described someone short as "knee high to a grasshopper", would you say these assessments would be useful even as order-of-magnitude estimates?

Comment: I could see Data having the strength of ten average men. An average man can carry 100 pounds for some distance but struggles with 200. 300 is out of the question for an average man. I don't think it's out of the realm of possibility that Data could carry 2000 pounds, though this is speculation, of course.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Picard doesn't strike me as the sort of person who'd choose a phrase carelessly. On top of that, we see him doing stuff that you'd need (at least) the strength of ten men to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one "bar" is 100 kilo pascals, or the equivalent of atmospheric pressure at sea level. So the largest measurement of his strength in bending the bar was 40k x 100k pascals. this turns out to be 580150.95202887 pounds per square inch. Essentially his subframe would give out before he could exert his full strength on anything.

Comment: How do you know that his subframe would give out?

Comment: as far as i could find in any starfleet materials guides, there is no known material that could withstand the strength generated by that power.  a small hand, say 4 x 4 inches is 16 square inches x 580150 lbs.  9282400 lbs in his hand is 4641.2 tons.  if it was the size of my hand it would have an approximate surface area of 36 x 580150 lbs. or 20,885,400 lbs. or 10,442.7 tons.  The ENTIRE EIFFEL TOWER is just over 10000 tons.  Data, for all the amazing he is, cannot lift the Eiffel Tower.