# What is the "default" strength level of Voyager's EMH?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

By "strength" I mean physical strength, not mental strength, combat strength, or anything else. As a being of forcefields and light, is the EMH stronger than the members of the crew (including Tuvok)? Or is he only about as strong as a typical human being of the same size and build?

Also, can the EMH become stronger through alteration of his program? I would assume so, but how strong? Strong enough to defeat all of Voyager's senior staff (or entire crew) in a Tug-of-War contest?

Comment: Since his strength (within sickbay) is merely a function of the maximum strength of the room's forcefield emitters, I suspect the answer to your second question is; strong enough to juggle the entire crew one-handed.

Comment: How many copycat questions are we going to get before this "how strong is ____?" fad dies out?

Comment: @DVK It's the most recent one (admittedly by different users).  I'm just annoyed at these questions that are, conceptually, copy/paste and change the character..

Comment: @Izkata - given that they are from widely different universes and produce whildly different answers due to that, I STILL don't see what the issue is?

Comment: @DVK If you're referring to the Terminator one, that was just the start.  There's also [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64050/how-strong-is-data) and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65909/are-cardassians-physically-stronger-than-humans) recently that I know of

Comment: @T-1000 could you also accept answers? or are all the answers to your questions not satisfactory in some way?

Comment: @Izkata - your point being? The site has 15,000 questions, not like these 4 swamp out other types. Do you also object to Story-ID questions on the same ground (every single one of them is 100% same, "I read that book, with ___ details, what is it"? Except there's a gazillion and a half of them. 2 out of last 10, for that matter. And they are all about random guessing.

Comment: @DVK "these 4" do not swamp out other types if you are on this site once a lifetime. However, many of us, including you, Izkata, and I, visit this site quite often. I suspect we have different reactions, but when I see what is essentially the same question over and over again in a short amount of time (and the questions sometimes not being relevant to the source other than the fact that a character is being asked about), it becomes frustrating

Comment: @calccrypto - An excellent point. Accepting answers you've posted is an essential part of the process.

Comment: @Izkata Not sure why all of my questions annoy you. If you don't like character strength questions, then you have a simple choice: ignore them.

Comment: @calccrypto I don't know what you mean by "accept" answers. I read all answers posted to questions I ask and appreciate anything that people offer. Except when people get needlessly upset, as Izkata did here, even though I'm asking about a science fiction character and one of his characteristics.

Comment: @T-1000 [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

In the third season episode "[Darkling](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Darkling_(episode))", the Doctor's program was infested by new behavioral subroutines.  He was strong enough to grab a full-grown man and *with one arm* hold that man immobile for several seconds while the man's hand was being burned over a raging fire.  This is much stronger than any single human of similar build.  Tangling with the Doctor is more like being grabbed by a chimp or maybe an industrial robot.  Given that the Doctor might be called upon to restrain convulsing humanoids such as Klingons and Vulcans who are known to have much greater than human strength, it makes sense that he could exert a large amount of force if warranted.

Comment: not exactly alien intelligence... more of an unexpected reaction between personality subroutines

Comment: It's worth noting that this is more to do with the strength of his mobile emitter than any sort of inherent strength of his programming (I propose). Then his strength on-board Voyager when using the integrated emitters would be an entirely different answer.